# Angular-ui-bootstrap.d.ts is a TypeScript analog for angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-bootstrap

Does anybody know is [angular-ui-bootstrap.d.ts](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/angular-ui-bootstrap) an analog for [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)?

Does it fully covers ui bootstrap functionality?  I tried to use TS $modal and seems that sometimes it works differently from it's js version.

Thanks, Vlad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is a TypeScript analog for angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap?

Yes. Based on project url :https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angular-ui-bootstrap/angular-ui-bootstrap.d.ts#L2

`ModalService` seems to be the analog for `$modal` https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angular-ui-bootstrap/angular-ui-bootstrap.d.ts#L171

> Does it fully covers ui bootstrap functionality? I tried to use TS $modal and seems that sometimes it works differently from it's js version.

A `.d.ts` is just a form of documentation. It can be out of date like any other documentation.